# How to use lambda-file-exists validation when not knowing the file name

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, lambdatest

Im creating an automation testing using Selenium+Lambda and have to validade if a file is downloaded.

I found the following solution in lambda support page
https://www.lambdatest.com/support/docs/download-files-using-lambdatest-selenium-grid/

Indeed i implemented the following and worked, my test its validating if a file is downloaded or not.
"**Assert.assertEquals(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("lambda-file-exists=myw3schoolsimage.jpg"), true);**"

The problem is.. i had to pass the file name hardcoded in that command, and that wont work for my scenarios as my files have dinamic names.

There is a way handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the downloaded file exists in the test machine.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("lambda-file-exists=file-name.file_format");
```

List down the file in the download directory.

```
print driver.execute_script("lambda-file-list={match string with filename}");
```

ie:

```
driver.execute_script("lambda-file-list=sample")
```

Response: List of files in downloads dir starting with sample